# Cannot start Jetty as a service on CentOS

Tags: jetty

When I try to launch jetty-9.0.3.v20130506 as a user or a service, I get an error as follows:

```
2013-06-24 00:00:36.927:WARN:oejs.Holder:main: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

When I add lib=lib to start.ini, I can run jetty as a user by launching the script. I do not understand how adding this standard location fixes it, but it does.

```
bin/jetty.sh start
```

When I try to launch jetty as a service, which uses the same script, it fails with the error given above.

It look like the start script does not use the start.ini when it is launched as a service because it does not process the lib=lib statement that solves the problem.

Can anyone offer a clear explanation as to how I can get jetty to load a CrossOriginFilter using the jars that are in the lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this one cause a LOT of pain.

you should not add this to start.ini

```
lib=lib
```

you should add this

```
lib=/<full path to jetty>/lib
```

When running as a service, the script does not apply the relative path for some reason, like it does with the other arguments in start.ini. Just use the full path.

The only thing I hate about SO is that I usually figure out the problem right after I post.

**UPDATE:** The solution below, adding servlets to the options, was the way to go. That was easy, but for some reason I did not see that in any other posts about the CrossOriginFilter.

Comment: You would be better off adding `OPTIONS=servlets` to the `start.ini` instead of using the `lib` directive.

Comment: I didn't realize, I will give that a try. I was surprised that the lib folder wasn't in the classpath, though. I guess am too much of a Java noob to understand how it finds and loads classes.